# Alamofire.request() errors out in Xcode 12

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire, swift5

I have a networking method using alamofire called **getPriceData()**, and inside of it an **Alamofire.request(url, method: .get)** that errors out twice, although this same method is used in another app project exactly the same and works fine. The errors:

> Module 'Alamofire' has no member named 'request'

> Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'get'

The method:

```
 func getPriceData(url: String) {
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get).responseJSON {
        response in
        if response.result.isSuccess {
            let priceJSON: JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
            self.updatePriceData(json: bitcoinJSON)
        } else {
            self.bitcoinPriceLabel.text = "N/A"
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the chunk of code and the two errors:
[The method and the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODXnu.jpg)

Comment: Please make sure You are using same Alamofire  Pod versions for both projects. Might possible the method has changed in latest pod version.

Comment: Help yourself by reading Alamofire Usage.  https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#using-alamofire

Comment: I checked alamofire versions and in the older project is 4.9.1 and in the newer is 5.4.0

Answer (score 2):

try this may be it will work for you :)

```
AF.request(url,method: .get).responseString{
                        responce in
                     }
```

Comment: Hey! thanks for help, I tried this and I've got three different errors in the lines inside the method which I don't really get why, maybe because its not reading AF as Alamofire? The errors are:

'isSuccess' is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level

Value of type 'Result<Any, AFError>' has no member 'value'

Cannot find 'bitcoinJSON' in scope

Comment: because in this version of alamofire there is no method named issucess so you can replace it with `if (try? responce.result.get()) != nil{` . , i hope this will help you and don't forget to upvote